# jquery/javascript, use one button to click/submit multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

Probably a stupid question but please bear with me on this one:

**Is it possible, with the use of jQuery/javascript, to make it so that when you click one button it clicks/submits multiple buttons?**

This will probably help make answering the question easier:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-status-10-field-status-und-select">
  <select size="0" name="field_status[10][field_status][und][select]" id="edit-field-status-10-field-status-und-select" class="select-or-other-select form-select chzn-done" style="width: 100px; display: none;">
    <option value="">- select -</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="In">In</option>
    <option value="Gym">Gym</option>
    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
    <option value="Out">Out</option>
    <option value="select_or_other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <div id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 100px;" title=""><a tabindex="-1" class="chzn-single" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>In</span></a>
    <div style="left: -9000px; width: 98px; top: 25px;" class="chzn-drop">
      <div class="chzn-search">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 63px;">
      </div>
      <ul class="chzn-results">
        <li style="" class="active-result" id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn_o_0">- select -</li>
        <li style="" class="active-result result-selected" id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn_o_1">In</li>
        <li style="" class="active-result" id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn_o_2">Gym</li>
        <li style="" class="active-result" id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn_o_3">Lunch</li>
        <li style="" class="active-result" id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn_o_4">Out</li>
        <li style="" class="active-result" id="edit_field_status_10_field_status_und_select_chzn_o_5">Other</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, bind the click event for one and trigger the others.

Comment: Whoa. That was a really quick response! Thanks Chad. If the buttons all had the same class name how would I go about doing that? For instance all the buttons that I want to be able to click with the one button have the class name '.processed'.

Comment: If you have specific forms you're asking about or need help with, it probably would be a good idea to include their HTML in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that does the trick for me:

```
// Find input(s) that have changed. Add class to their hidden submit button.
$(function() {
    $("input, select").change(function() {
        $(this).closest('td').find('input.ajax-processed').addClass("changed");
    });
});

// One button to submit all input(s) that have changed.
$('.submit-all').click(function(){
    $('.changed, input[type=button]').not('.submit-all').trigger('click');
});
```

Thanks guys for all of your help. It took a combination of all of your advice to get this beast working and it also helped me to rethink what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

This way:

```
<input type="button" id="triggerAll">

<input type="button" class="button1">
<input type="button" class="button2">
<input type="button" class="button3">
```

```
$('#triggerAll').on('click',function(){
    $('.button1,.button2,.button3').trigger('click');
});
```

Or this way:

```
<input type="button" id="triggerAll">

<input type="button" class="processed">
<input type="button" class="processed">
<input type="button" class="processed">
```

```
$('#triggerAll').on('click',function(){
    $('.processed').trigger('click');
});
```

Or this way:

```
<form class="monitorChanges">
    <label>
        Pick one:
        <select data-defaultvalue="" name="other">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>
        Other:
        <input type="text" data-defaultvalue="" name="other">
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<input type="text" value="Trigger All" id="triggerAll">
```

```
$('.monitorChanges').on('change keyup',"input,textarea,select",function(){
    var defaultValue = $(this).data('defaultvalue');

    if ($(this).val() !== defaultValue){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="submit"]:not(.processed)').addClass('processed');
    }
    else {
       $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="submit"].processed').removeClass('processed');
    }
});

$('#triggerAll').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().find('form input[type="submit"].processed').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Thank you DJDavid98. That worked beautifully. Sorry to expand upon this question but is there a way to make it so that only forms that have had their values changed will have their buttons triggered?

Comment: @user2266174 See my edit, and don't forget to mark this as your final answer with the green tick.

Comment: Hey DJDavid98. For some reason that last bit of code made my forms disappear. Is '.monitorChanges' the class name of the form where the values are being changed? Sorry, I should have note this!: The form is a drop-down list with an "Other" option that presents a textfield.

Comment: @user2266174 See my edit again. Also if you don't have `<label>` tags in your actual HTML, you should remove one of the 2 `.parent()`s from the code.

Comment: I can't quite seem to get it to work. I was able to get the forms to appear once I added {} after the else statement and put a semicolon at the end of the first function but it's still not behaving properly. I would provide a link to show you what the form looks like but the website is on https and is internal only :( Is there maybe a simpler way by which to detect if a user has changed the dropdown form? Maybe a bit of code that could detect if they simply touched the drop-down list? No need to detect if they changed it from the default value or anything.

Comment: @user2266174 Fixed the else statement. If you need further support with the code, please add me on skype: `guzsik.david`.

Comment: Thanks David. You've been very helpful. I'm gonna mark this off as an accepted answer. Please continue to keep this convo in your pipeline though. I'm going to give your updated code snippet a shot in a little bit once I square some stuff away with my code.

Comment: Hey David, are you able to get your code to work with my html at the top? I've changed the class names in the jquery code you provided to match my html but I can't seem to get it to work. I'd skype you if I could but I'm on a locked down network so no go on any chat engines or VoIP soft.

Comment: @user2266174 Look, I'm only here to help, not to write all of your code. You have to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: Wow...I'm not asking you to write my code for me. Sorry if it came across that way. I was just following up on your comment: "If you have specific forms you're asking about or need help with, it probably would be a good idea to include their HTML in the question itself." For now I'm going to unmark this as the accepted answer since it doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm sure you could prove me wrong on this one but until then I'll keep chipping away at it and repost here.

Comment: @user2266174 Your HTML doesn't have any buttons in it, maybe I could help better if you included your code for the buttons (and their forms, if any) as well.

Comment: Hi David, see my solution below. Feel free to critique.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mybtnId').click(function(){
    $('button, input[type=button]').not('#mybtnId').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example specific to you:

```
$('.processed').on('click', function (e) {
    //real event
    if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {
        $('.processed').click();
    }
    //manually triggered event
    else {
           alert($(this).text() + ' triggered');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps! You can see it working in this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vtwxL/3/)

Comment: Thanks Chad! Is there also a way to make it so that only forms that have had their values changed will have their buttons triggered?

Comment: Sure, just add some data property to the form like `$(form).data('updated', false);` and set it to true whenever it updates, then loop through each form and check if it was updated and trigger it's submit.

Comment: @Chad What if the user then deletes the data? The field will be empty again, but the data attribute will still mark the updated state.

Comment: Hey guys, don't know how much this changes the convo but the form is a drop-down with an option for "Other" that presents a textfield to users.

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me, using pure JavaScript. I used the `onclick` event on a list item (`li`) containing two reset `button`'s. They control different `form`'s and one of them is not displayed in the list item (`style="display:none;"`). Of course, you can make the same implementation in any type of input.

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="document.getElementById('btn-clear-1').click(); document.getElementById('btn-clear-2').click();">
    <input class="btn" id="btn-clear-1" form="frm1" type="reset" value="Clear" />
    <input class="btn" id="btn-clear-2" form="frm2" type="reset" value="Clear" style="display:none;" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

But what I did is unnecessary code for what I was looking for. It could be `<li onclick="document.getElementById('#frm1').reset(); document.getElementById('#frm2').reset();">Clear</li>`
(Commentary made only to avoid bad coding in this board)